# Switching from Oracle database to Ubuntu

Tags: oracle, database-design, ubuntu

I need support please.

I am the CEO of a Life Assurance company. We are currently building our own core application under the leadership of my Head of ISD. We are using Oracle for our database and also using other supportive Oracle applications. My question is this:

- Preamble; i want to get rid of the expensive Oracle licensing cost and convert our database/platform to Ubuntu. The question; Can this be done i.e. dump Oracle and change the company over to Ubuntu systems?

I would really like to speak to someone that understands these systems and who would be able to give me advice on swhitching over to Ubuntu and what the cost will be.

Comment: I'm sorry your question doesn't make sense. Ubuntu is an operating system, not a database.

Comment: @FreddeBeer, you can't. because Oracle is Database and Ubuntu is Linux operating system.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the Ubuntu range of products, a product that can be used to replace the Oracle database? or, can Ubuntu fullfill all the OS/Database requirements of a large organization? Would you be able to point me in the right direction please?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the Ubuntu range of products". And Ubuntu can _not_ "fullfill the database requirements of a large organization", because Ubuntu is an operating system, not a DBMS.  All modern (open source) DBMS do run on Ubuntu, so you just need to pick the  DBMS that you want. Postgres would be a good choice.

Comment: Sure: run a PostgreSQL database and build your apps in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: @FreddeBeer, Ubuntu can't fullfill the database requirements for any firm or organizations. Because it's a multi user/Multi tasking OS. as you can follow the a_horse_with_no_name comments.

Answer (score 4):

Though I have serious doubts in your description, let's first clean up some misconceptions.

1. Oracle is what is called a [Relational Database Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) or RDBMS (the company developing it is called Oracle For short, too). It is used – who would have guessed it – to store and retrieve data based on its relations. It requires an operating system to run.
2. Ubuntu is an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) or OS. Windows is an example for an operating system, while Ubuntu technically and strictly speaking isn't. It is a collection of programs, tools and the [Linux Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) (or GNU/Linux as some, including me, call it for political reasons), called a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)

So technically, you could (but shouldn't even try in production environments) to run the Oracle RDBMS on Ubuntu.

Since you are referring to Oracle's license costs which you want to get rid of, I assume you want a free (as in beer) alternative to the Oracle RDBMS. While there are some pretty mature and powerful free RDBMS out there, you should first take other things into account.

1. Most likely, the software running your key business was written specifically for Oracle. While in theory, every SQL database should be interchangeable, the reality couldn't be further away from that theory than it is today. One step more, and most of the SQL RDBMS today would be proprietary storage engines. So when changing your RDBMS, take into account that parts of your software have to be rewritten, tested, test deployed and retested to make sure your core business isn't interrupted after the migration.
2. Your existing data has to be migrated from Oracle to the new RDBMS. We are not talking of simply copying some files from disk A to disk B. Data formats have to be changed, types converted, and a whole lot more. Data migration is ***expensive***. You need highly trained and ***very*** well paid specialists to do it properly. I know one case where such data migration netted over €300,000 – not including losses due to maintenance windows.
3. Your HR department will have a hard time finding proven experts for open source databases, simply because the certification infrastructure – forgivemy French – sucks. There simply is (close to) none. For Oracle, it is easy: Have a RedHat Certified System Administrator for the OS, an Oracle Certified Database Administrator for the RDBMS and you are done. You can easily prove that your guys know their job, which might be necessary in some cases - think of a class action where you have to prove that you and your guys did the best they possibly could to protect sensitive data of your customers.

Don't get me wrong – I love free RDBMS (both as in "beer" and as in "speech"), but I have serious doubts that your have the technical knowledge to even have a slight idea what to look at before making a decision like this. Get a CTO / CIO you trust. If you have one and you don't trust him or her, either try to get along or fire him or her.

Comment: Small note: "*they are currently building their own core application*". I don't think they'll need migrating anything. Changing their app and data type yes, but 300K for a migration? Not probable at that stage of development, I'd think.

Comment: In short, I totally agree with 1, agree with 2 but I think is not entirely relevant, and disagree with 3. It may be harder to find certified professionals for Postgres but it won't be hard to find good professionals.

Comment: They already have "supportive applications". As for the price: use cases have to be defined, the optimal new structure modeled and tested, there have to be test migrations, approvals or rejections by the individual business units to be incorporated and the whole migrations to be refined. Rinse and repeat that two or three times and do the actual migration. Count the days. Assume moderate 1k/day per person involved.

Comment: Oops, you are right, I missed that part (about supportive applications). You have my +1 anyway, despite my disagreement on 3 ;)

Comment: I agree that you can find good Postgres professionals. You could. I could. The average HR? Not so much. And when it comes to legal stuff, you are going to have a hard time. Same goes for professional development of the employees.

Comment: Dear Markus and evilcube, many thanks for you very valuable comments. It certainly creates better insights into what Oracle is vs Ubuntu. I was previously under the impression that Ubuntu would be able to be a replacement database, but realize now that it cannot be the case for reasons you explained here.

Comment: Dear Markus and evilcube, many thanks for you very valuable comments. It certainly creates better insights into what Oracle is vs Ubuntu. I was previously under the impression that Ubuntu would be able to be a replacement database, but realize now that it cannot be the case for reasons you explained here.

Comment: As an insurer, we have serious bills when it comes to licensing compliance for our OS's as well database/data center/DR site running on Oracle. It is in this context that my intial enquiry came from. We don't internally have the knowledge set to bring onboard other RDBMS. So for me the first step will be to do away with the Microsoft OS on our computers and bring a free OS onboard such as Ubuntu, which I believe is a very stable OS. Would you be so kind to refer me to someone that can advice me on alternative RDBMS's, many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Fred, you might want to contact me via xing.